# Protection for wysiwyg data to sql

Tags: php, wysiwyg, froala

Am using froala editor (WYSIWYG editor)

Am saving all `<textarea>` to sql using following code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sanoj";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO wysiwyg (savesql)  VALUES (:savesql)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':savesql', $savesql);
        // insert a row
    $savesql = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'store');
        $stmt->execute();


    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

Since am using WYSIWYG there are various library from froala

Do i need to create validation for user input or these library will protect from `PHP` attack

### this is how i echo data from sql

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "sanoj";
        $password = "123456";
        $dbname = "test";

// Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $sql = "SELECT memberID, savesql FROM wysiwyg";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "id: " . $row["memberID"] . " - Name: " . $row["savesql"];
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Comment: Only if you're doing something like `eval()` on the code you're storing (which is probably a bad idea). If not, just do `htmlentities()` on it before ouputting it to the browser.

Comment: @Mike check my question made some edit thats method i echo data

Comment: Silly question, but why are you mixing mysqli and PDO? Also, you're not escaping `$row['savesql']`, so beware that a user could inject javascript or whatever they want into there. Considering it's a WYSIWYG editor I suppose that `htmlentities()` (as I mentioned above) would not be viable. So instead you might want to use something like [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to whitelist certain tags and strip everything else.

Comment: @Mike but above code is from W3 school

Comment: Unfortunately w3schools is not always the best resource to use. They have amazing SEO and appear at the top of many (if not most) relevant searches, but their code is often very buggy. It doesn't make sense to use two MySQL APIs. I think most people prefer PDO, but use either PDO or mysqli, but not both. The code above is vulnerable to XSS attacks, so using something like htmlpurifier should fix that if done right. See also https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29 if you don't understand what XSS is.